# How do I create a histogram in R with x coordinates having nonnumeric labels and frequency totals shown

Tags: r, histogram, usage-statistics

I am creating a simulated dataset and I want to create a histogram based on x values that are not numeric.  Here is what I have:

```
x <- c("CF", "CH", "CJ", "CE", "CN", "EC", "EN", "EJ", "AB", "BA", "KO", "OD", "DL", "HG")
px = c(0.08, 0.10, 0.06, 0.20, 0.04, 0.15, 0.02, 0.10, 0.025, 0.025, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
draws = sample(x, size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = px)
hist( draws)
```

I would like the histogram to have the values for x as labels and also each of the bars to show the total frequency that each value of x was sampled.  Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 8):

You mean a barchart?

```
> barplot(height=table(draws))
```

[image]